# Running VBA code on external powerpoint file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to run VBA code from a certain powerpoint file on an external powerpoint file without copying the code into the external powerpoint file. I wish to only open the original powerpoint file containing the code and run it from there, it should point to the external powerpoint file and alter it directly. How to do this?

So far I am doing it like this:

```vb
    'For each file, if powerpoint run remove alt text macro
    For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

        'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
        sFileExtension = FSOFile.GetExtensionName()
    
        If sFileExtension = "pptm" Or sFileExtension = "pptx" Or sFileExtension = "ppt" Then
            Dim PPT As Object

            Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

            PPT.Presentations.Open (FSOFile.Path)

            ' Note that the file name and the module
            ' name are required to path the macro correctly.
            PPT.Run (ActivePresentation.Path + "!Module1.BlankAllTheAltText")
            filesAltered = filesAltered + 1
        End If

    Next
```

I don't think this is correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Using VBA, open the file to be operated on, and pass a reference to that file to the code you need to run to alter the file.  If you post your actual code someone might have a more-specific suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i've added my code

Comment: Does it work? If so, it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already running this from within PPT, you don't need to create a PPT application object. Try something more like this:

```
Dim oPres As Presentation

'For each file, if powerpoint run remove alt text macro
For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files

    'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
    sFileExtension = FSOFile.GetExtensionName()
    
    If sFileExtension = "pptm" Or sFileExtension = "pptx" Or sFileExtension = "ppt" Then
    
        Set oPres = Presentations.Open(FSOFile.Path)
        ' Alter BlankAllTheAltText to take a presentation object
        ' as a parameter
        Call BlankAllTheAltText(oPres)
        
        filesAltered = filesAltered + 1
    
        oPres.Save
        oPres.Close
    
    End If

Next
```